# is it necessary to destroy all SESSION(at the time of LOGOUT) those I start after LOGIN in PHP?

Tags: php, session-variables

1. Is it necessary to destroy all SESSION(at the time of LOGOUT) those I start after LOGIN in PHP ?
2. How can I destroy all SESSION variable ?
3. Life time of SESSION variable ?
4. If I do not destroy session then it stores the value for next login user ?

   ```
   $_SESSION['docid'] = $docid;
       header("Location:patappointtime.php");

   $_SESSION['docname'] = $docname;
       header("Location:patappointtime.php");

   $_SESSION['docdept'] = $docdept;
       header("Location:patappointtime.php");
   ```

I have to destroy only `session[docid]`...or I have to destroy all of the three sessions ?

Comment: all, no. the one that says logged in vs not, yes.

Comment: use session and cokie together, and use google for this

Comment: please elaborate your answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply destroy a session: $_SESSION["sessionname"] = NULL.

If you want to destroy them all: session_destroy()

But why you want to destroy them if the user is logged???... I don't understand you

Comment: that means if i write "session_destroy" it destroy all the session variables those i set previously..it does not store information for the next user..

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not necessary, but it's about security, and it's not recommended to leave any data when we don't need it.

To destroy a session, you can use `session_destroy()`, but, as it's said in official docs, *it does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.*

To completely remove a session, cookie and all associated variables, here's an example on [official docs page](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php):

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

If session was **not** destroyed on the server, it lives as long as cookie is set, and [here's setting for it](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime): `session.cookie-lifetime`.